# How can I force the usage of a class from a particular jar and exclude same class of another jar in build.sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly, jnr

I have two `asm` dependencies that have exactly the same class names and project structures included by different dependencies. Although these libraries have the same project structure, they have different Maven coordinates. Therefore, a dependency override won't work.

A one of my dependencies ([`jnr-ffi`](https://github.com/web3j/web3j)) uses a the `org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor` class. In `"org.objectweb" % "asm" % "3.3.1"`, `org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor` is an Interface, and this throws an error. I need to use `"org.ow2.asm" % "asm" % "5.0.3"`'s implementation of `org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor` because it is an actual class. Jars of both implementations are downloaded into `~/.ivy2/cache`. Unfortunately the one I need isn't used given my merge strategies.

The following error is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor, but class was expected
at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.AsmLibraryLoader.generateInterfaceImpl(AsmLibraryLoader.java:104)
at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.AsmLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(AsmLibraryLoader.java:89)
at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:43)
at jnr.ffi.LibraryLoader.load(LibraryLoader.java:325)
at jnr.unixsocket.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:80)
at jnr.unixsocket.UnixSocketChannel.<init>(UnixSocketChannel.java:101)
at jnr.unixsocket.UnixSocketChannel.open(UnixSocketChannel.java:65)
```

I'm using `sbt` 0.13.5 and `sbt assembly` 0.14.2 .

I've attempted exclude `"org.objectweb" % "asm" % "3.3.1"`. This did not work:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(. . .).map(_.exclude("org.objectweb" % "asm" % "3.3.1"))
```

I've also attempted to use the following merge strategies

```
    assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
      case PathList("asm-3.2.jar") => MergeStrategy.discard
      case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith ".asm-3.2.jar" => MergeStrategy.discard
      case PathList("asm-5.0.3.jar") => MergeStrategy.first
      case PathList(ps @ _*) if ps.last endsWith ".asm-5.0.3.jar" => MergeStrategy.first
      case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
      case x => MergeStrategy.first
    }
```

I've also tried excluding the jar:

```
    assemblyExcludedJars in assembly := {
      val cp = (fullClasspath in assembly).value
      cp filter {_.data.getName == "asm-3.2.jar"}
    }
```

I've also tried to implement the custom merge strategy `project/IncludeFromJar.scala` from ["How can a duplicate class be excluded from sbt assembly?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24363363/how-can-a-duplicate-class-be-excluded-from-sbt-assembly). But `IncludeFromJar.scala` won't compile, and I believe its because I'm using the wrong version of `sbt assembly` for their example.

`case PathList("org", "objectweb", "asm", "ClassVisitor.class") => new IncludeFromJar("asm-5.0.3.jar")`

Hence the question:
How can I force the usage of a class from a particular jar and exclude same class of another jar in build.sbt?

Comment: hi, maybe you could have a look at dependencyOverrides in the sbt manual
https://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html

Comment: @étienne they have different Maven coordinates. Therefore, a dependency override won't work :x

Answer (score 2):

I've lately faced a similar issue. The solution I've found was to use dependencies shading for assembly. Here are the settings I've used within my `build.sbt` file.

```scala
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("org.objectweb.asm.**" -> "asm503.@1").inLibrary(
    "org.ow2.asm" % "asm" % "5.0.3"
  ).inLibrary(
    "org.ow2.asm" % "asm-tree" % "5.0.3"
  ).inLibrary(
    "org.ow2.asm" % "asm-analysis" % "5.0.3"
  ).inLibrary(
    "org.ow2.asm" % "asm-commons" % "5.0.3"
  ).inLibrary(
    "org.ow2.asm" % "asm-util" % "5.0.3"
  ).inLibrary(
    "com.github.jnr" % "jnr-ffi" % "2.1.9"
  ).inProject // For your own code
)
```

The `.inProject` statement will shade your own imports as well (if needed).

I know the thread is old but this might help someone.